# Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn Super slow after trying to install nvidia drivers

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 14.10

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 that has both an Intel Graphics Media chip, and a GeForce GT 525M Graphics Card.

I recently clean installed Ubuntu 14.10 after having upgraded from 14.04 and running into this issues, the system became super slow, just doing anything...

After doing the clean install though, i was just setting everything up properly to my taste and then I tried to install the Nvidia drivers for my graphics card... it was a disaster... resolution was 1024x768, unity dash and top bar wouldnt appear and i couldnt even bring up a terminal... After a series of workarounds involving the CompizConfig Settings Manager, i was able to bring back the dash and top bar and even the proper resolution.

The problem now, is the system is super slow again, and i every time i boot up, i get the following message: `init: Error while reading from descriptor: Broken pipe`

Do you think there is any way of solving this without have to clean install everything again? can i reinstall all the unity related packages? it might solve it, i think... how do i find out all packages related to unity?

Thanks, if any further info is needed, just ask

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. Also how did you install the drivers?

Comment: Did you install the nvidia driver in the official source or add a ppa?